# How do you bind a polygon to a marker using leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Does leaflet have a built in way of binding polygons and other objects together? Specifically I want to bind a number of polygons to a marker. Right now I have a work around that is listening to the marker's location, and everytime it moves it is removing and recreating the polygons.

Just to note, I have searched the API documentation strenuously.